# When integration of this polynomial is minimum

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-calculus, quadrature

For which $x_k$ $$\int_a^b \prod_{k=1
}^n(x-x_k)$$ is minimum?

It was given in my book that this is minimum at if we pick $x_j $ as roots of Chebyshev polynomials of second kind. But there is no proof. Would anyone suggest me where can I study these

Comment: That claim is certainly only correct for $a=-1$, $b=1$ and also you may want to minimize the *absolute value* of the integral

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen could you suggest me a book to study numerical integration more rigoursly.

Comment: If $n$ is odd, it is clear that the integral is zero for many cases - e.g., pick one $x_k=\frac{a+b}2$ and place the remaining symmetrically.

Comment: And after change of variable it's symmetric about origin hence zero